# Route parameters in react

Tags: reactjs

I have many routes

```
<Route exact path="/"  component={Test} />
<Route exact path="/1"  component={Test1} />
<Route exact path="/2"  component={Test2} />
```

In every component i use `useLocation` to get the data from route. It exists a possibility to pass in `Route` a parameter and to access that parameter with `useLocation`, in every component?

**Here is the example:**

```
<Route exact path="/" parameter='this is route nr 1'  component={Test} />
<Route exact path="2/" parameter='this is route nr 2'  component={Test2} />
```

Which is the solution to do what i want to achieve?

Comment: All the components in your use case seem to be unique, why do you want to use location to get the parameters?

Comment: @Agney, you are right, all parameters will be different. I need the parameters to do some logic depending by the opened component. The parameter which i will get will be used in a hook what is common for all components. If i will be able to get that parameter in another way, without useLocation, it is ok. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

For query params you don't need to do anything extra in `<Route />`. You just need to get those query params in component and parse it

To access param1 from url

`/?param1=hello`

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const Test = () => {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
  return (
    <div>Test {queryParams.get('param1')}</div>
  );
}
```

And if you want path params like

`/1` // 1 from this route

In routes and you don't need to create multiple routes just to get 1,2 etc

```
<Route exact path="/:id" component={Test} />
```

In component

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const Test = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>Test ID: {id}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question that you search for a way to pass data to routes only at the router declaration. therefore you can use regular props instead of location data extract -

---

```
 <Route exact path="/" render={()=><Test parameter={'this is route nr 1'} />} />
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass props to the component directly using render:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={props => <MyComponent {...props} foo="hello world" bar={false} /> }
/>
```

or you can use query params:

```
<Route
  exact
  path={`/user?id=${user_id}`}
  component={MyComponent}
/>
```

and then in `MyComponent` you can access `props.match.params.id`

[React-router](https://reacttraining.com/) docs are a great start